# list values dosen't show up in c:foreach loop

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jstl

I'm trying add comment func on website and it dosen't show up in foreach loop.

```
@RequestMapping("list.do")
public ModelAndView list(@RequestParam int bId, ModelAndView mav){
    List<ReplyDto> listReply = replyService.listReply(bId);
    mav.setViewName("board/replyList");
    mav.addObject("list", listReply);
    return mav;
}
```

replyList.jsp

```
<c:forEach var="row" items="${list}">
<tr>
    ${row.memId}
    ${row.rText}                    
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

ReplyDto is below:

```
public class ReplyDto {
    private Integer rId;        // reply num
    private Integer bId;        // board num
    private String rText;    // reply text
    private String memId;   

    public Integer getrId() {
        return rId;
    }
    public void setrId(Integer rId) {
        this.rId = rId;
    }
    public Integer getbId() {
        return bId;
    }
    public void setbId(Integer bId) {
        this.bId = bId;
    }
    public String getrText() {
        return rText;
    }
    public void setrText(String rText) {
        this.rText = rText;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: show your ReplyDto class

Comment: @user7294900 Edited!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`memId` and `rText` are private so it can't be reached, use public Getters instead:

```
<tr>
    ${row.getmemId()} 
    ${row.getrText()}                    
</tr>
```

Also follow [Java/Oracle conventions for Methods](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html):

> Methods should be verbs, in mixed case with the first letter
>   lowercase, with the first letter of each internal word capitalized.

So consider change method names e.g. from `getrText` to `getRText`